# Error al consumir WS SOAP desde VS2015 con C#

Tags: c#

Estimados

Dentro de VS 2015 con C# he creado un proyecto dll en el cual hago una referencia a un WS de uno de nuestros proveedores, luego de ello he creado un proyecto de pruebas unitarias en donde llamo al servicio sin más con su constructor

```
 ServiceHotelClient serviceHotelClient = new  ServiceHotelClient();
```

agregué el namespace necesario con `using` y resulta que tengo el siguiente error

```
El código de usuario no controló System.InvalidOperationException
    HResult=-2146233079
    Message=No se encontró el elemento de extremo predeterminado que hace referencia al contrato 'WSServiceReference.IServiceHotel' en la sección de configuración de cliente de ServiceModel. La razón puede ser que no se encontró ningún archivo de configuración para la aplicación o que no se encontró ningún elemento de extremo correspondiente a este contrato en el elemento de cliente.
    Source=System.ServiceModel
    StackTrace:
        en System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
        en System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
        en System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
        en System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
        en System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
        en System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
        en System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
        en System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
        en System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
        en System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
        en BusinessAgent_WS.WSServiceReference.ServiceHotelClient..ctor() en D:\Codigo\BusinessAgent_WS\BusinessAgent_WS\Service References\WSServiceReference\Reference.cs:línea 1630
        en Netactica.Net.Core.Source.WS.WSManager..ctor(Credential credential) en D:\Codigo\BusinessAgent_WS\BusinessAgent_WS\WSManager.cs:línea 24
        en UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() en D:\Codigo\BusinessAgent_WS\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:línea 34
    InnerException:
```

Agradecería el apoyo de Uds.

Comment: Podrías mostrar como tienes tu webconfig ?¿ te esta haciendo falta el binding que direcciona al servicio.

Comment: Es necesario tener esto ya que mi proyecto es de dll y solo lo llamo desde una prueba unitaria es como si fuera una aplicación de escritorio.

Comment: Si es necesario, que tengas esta configuración en tu App.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que copiar la seccion de configuracion que se creo en el app.config del proyecto class library al config del proyecto de test

Recuerda que la configuracion se lee de forma automatica desde el config del proyecto que inicia la ejecucion, en este caso el de pruebas unitarias, es alli donde debes tener la seccion de configuracion que hace uso del proxy que se crea al realiza la web reference.

En el `app.config` del proyecto `Class Library` veras una seccion `serviceModel` esa es la que deberas llevar al `app.config` pero del proyecto de `unit test`, ya que desde alli levantara la configuracion la dll cuando ejecutes

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no hallo un app.config en el proyecto de test, pegue el archivo que generó el proxy en el test y sigue el error. Hay que hacer algo para que lo reconozca.

Comment: Lo he conseguido, debido a que el WS me traía dos enpoints iguales, borré uno y se arregló claro que tuve que crear el archivo app.config en el proyecto de test. Gracias por la ayuda.